# hashtable search function not working for certain cases

Tags: c++

the search function will take in a key value which is a const string& and it will look in the hashtable to see if the key value item is found or not..

my code here works except for a few cases (for example when i pass in "ZZ0" in to the function).

not sure if its because i'm using `==` instead of `strcmp`

But i can't see why it would not work simply because of that. can someone please explain if i'm missing something here?

```
void HT::search(const string& item)
{
    int index=hash(item);
    bool found=false;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<hsize;i++)
    {
        if(hTable[(index+i)%hsize].key==item)
        {
            found=true;
            cout<<"item found";
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        cout<<" : Item not found!"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: In C++, `==` is the correct way to compare two strings for equality (as long as they are both indeed `std::string`).

Comment: You should show your hash function.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use open address for collision and I don't see any problem here. Are you sure that your string "ZZO" has been inserted into the hash table correctly? I suggest you do a unit test to check that. Just insert the string and iterate the hashtable see whether it exists.

BTW, I suggest you use [Separate chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) to implement the hashtable because it's easy to implemented and generally more efficient(Well definitely depends on your hash function). And it could be further extended to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Even without seeing your insert function code -- I suggest to you that your 'insert' function is the problem -- it most likely does not handle hash collisions and simply override some values/elements -- why don't you post your code for the insert function as well?